# Why am I getting null pointer exception in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting `NullPointerException` for the above code. I am not able to understand where it is passing a null value.

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.driver" is null
 at com.example.PageObjects.DiscoverObjects.Splash_nextt(DiscoverObjects.java:60)
 at com.example.TestCases.Test.verify_open_application_land_on_disocver_tab(Test.java:37)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

Code:
[image]

Comment: It looks like `driver` is `null` when `new DiscoverObjects(driver)` is called.  The initialization  of `Test` (and of `ds`) happens before `setup()` is called.

Comment: Initialize `ds` in the `setup()` method ... AFTER you have created the driver and loaded the page whose objects you want to discover.